# Parse Update Object with Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

My goal was simply updating an existing object. However, I keep on getting this : **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)**

Here's my snippet of code :

```
    var FoodItem = Parse.Object.extend("food");
var query = new Parse.Query(FoodItem);
query.get("MEfRE1AlQp", {success: function(food ) {


 food.set('name',foodName);
 food.set('description',foodDescription);
 food.set('price',foodPrice);
 food.save();
 // -----------------------------------400 ERROR , NEED ASSISTANCE----------------------------------- },error: function(object, error) {}});
```

Any suggestions would help alot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

The issue was that price was a integer and I was trying to set a string to an integer.

What I did to solve this issue was that I used "Number(foodPrice)" to convert it to an integer.And the the 400 Request goes away.